# Java LinkedHashMap with removeEldestEntry causes java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, dictionary, get, linkedhashmap, lru

The error looks like this

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.remove(LinkedHashMap.java:332)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.recordAccess(LinkedHashMap.java:356)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.get(LinkedHashMap.java:304)
    at Server.getLastFinishedCommands(Server.java:9086)
    at Server.processPacket(Server.java:484)
    at PacketWorker.run(PacketWorker.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Inside `getLastFinishedCommands` I use

```
   public List<CCommand> getLastFinishedCommands(UserProfile player) {
        List<CCommand> returnList = new ArrayList<CCommand>();

        if(!finishedCommands.containsKey(player.myWebsitecmd-1)) {
            getSavedState(player);
            return null;
        }

        try { //<-- added this try/catch so it doesn't happen again.
            //Get commands.
            CCommand cmd;
            long i;
            long startIndex = player.myWebsitecmd;
            long endIndex = startIndex+LIMIT_COMMANDS;

            for(i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
                cmd = finishedCommands.get(i);   //<-- this is line 9086
                if(cmd == null) {
                    return returnList;
                }
                returnList.add(cmd);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {} //<-- added this try/catch so it doesn't happen again.
        return returnList;
    }
```

I wanted to make a Map that auto removes old entries so I used this snippet

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> createLRUMap(final int maxEntries) {
    return new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(maxEntries*3/2, 0.7f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxEntries;
        }
    };
}
```

Used it like this

```
public static int final MAX_COMMANDS_QUEUE = 5000;
public Map<Long, CCommand> finishedCommands = createLRUMap(MAX_COMMANDS_QUEUE);
```

Obviously it's some kind of CocurrentModifcationException which happens when using with multiple threads.. but why does it crash internally, anyone know how I can use this with like a CocurrentHashMap? I'm trying to fix this without resorting to just putting a try/catch around the whole `getLastFinishedCommands` function.

I want a Map that clears itself from old junk but still holds atleast 5000 key/value entries.

Comment: Do not ever use empty catch block. This is way to hell.

Comment: As a temporary solution I put a `try/catch` hopefully it will work for now, still looking how to fix it the right way without adding external classes or libraries

Comment: I think that your code is correct. I just looked to my implementation and it is the same. Could it be bug in JDK?

Comment: Please remove the empty `try-catch` block. This is not part of the source that has this issue and confuses matters. Could you post `java -version`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that multiple threads are accessing this map. This could indeed cause the NPE in the `remove` operation of a `LinkedHashMap.Entry` instance. This is the implementation of this method:

```
private void remove() {
    before.after = after;
    after.before = before;
}
```

Here `before` and after `refer` to the linked predecessor and successor of the current entry. If another thread already changed the linking between the entries, this could of course result in an unexpected behavior, such as the NPE.

The solution is - you guessed correctly - to wrap your produced map in a synchronized map. Such as:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> createLRUMap(final int maxEntries) {
    Map<K,V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(maxEntries*3/2, 0.7f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxEntries;
        }
    };
    return Collections.synchronizedMap(result);
}
```

This synchronized wrapper will indeed synchronize all calls to the underlying map, so only one single thread is allowed to go through each method (such as get, put, contains, size, and so on).

Comment: perfect I couldnt figure out how to make a function compile without having it as `found:    Map<Object,Object>` `required: Map<Long,CCommand>`

Answer (score 5):

Based on the stacktrace, I assume that the code tries to remove the value from an index whose item has been already removed by another thread. This makes it to throw `NPE` while accessing the properties of a `null` reference. Probably, you should try synchronizing the collection

From the documentation of `LinkedHashMap`

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a linked hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the map:

```
   Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
```

Comment: Could I wrap the Map around with `Collections.synchronizedMap` or that will still cause same issue? like this `public Map<Long, CCommand> finishedCommands = Collections.synchronizedMap(createLRUMap(MAX_COMMANDS_QUEUE)<Long, CComand>);`

Comment: Yes, you can very well use it. Give it a try! This should solve this problem since `it returns a synchronized (thread-safe) map backed by the specified map. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing map is accomplished through the returned map`

Comment: @SSpoke are you saying that you are using the `Map` in a concurrent environment? `Collections.synchronizedMap` is incredibly crude and may well _not_ work - if this `Map` is used concurrently you need to be very careful and **fully** understand and race hazards.

Comment: The `finishedCommands` are generated by one thread every 10 milliseconds and when a user connects to the website it requests the `finishedCommands` at a certain range could be any range of `Long`, Also the range shouldn't skip any if it does then it should return instantly as far as it got. If it doesn't get anything it'll just request it a second time and should get it next time I guess? But yeah.. I don't want to slow down the process which puts the commands into the `finishedCommads` Map.

Comment: @SSpoke You probably could, looking at your code, solve the issue with `Collections.synchronizedMap` as long as you don't mind items disappearing from the `Map` as you are looping.